# Generating Id's Server vs Client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vue.js, client-server

If I'm using something like React/Vue/Angular or just simply preventing my page to load on submit with pure JS, should I generate the id for my element on the front end or should I wait for the server to respond with an id?

A simple example would be the good old todo list, I add a todo and it has to have an id so when I want to delete it I can send the id to the server. In the past I used to generate a UUID and send that to the server for it to use. My question is just if this is good practice or should I be doing it differently?

Comment: Since ids are used to uniquely identify data in the database, you should always generate them server side. Also, this question is opinion-based.

Comment: @PrestonGarvey yes i know they should be unique and that it is safer for me to generate them server side, but what i'm asking is if i'm submitting something and sending it to the server to store it in my database but do not want to refresh my whole page and adding it by pushing to my array with javascript i also need the id to send later if i want to delete it maybe. Should i submit my form and wait for the response and then add the element? And doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of not refreshing my page?

Comment: Submit your form, send back the generated id in the response body, wait for it and then update your list. I don't see why you can't do this asynchronously.

Comment: This sounds like faulty strategy. You can still use UUID on client side if you need purely for client-side needs (e.g. unique id for unsynced entries or React `key`) but it isn't a substitute for database ids, just because it may be inconvenient to use UUIDs for that. *Should i submit my form and wait for the response and then add the element?* - not necessarily, you can add it to DOM immediately for usability reasons, then update elements with `id`s that were received in the response, or remove elements if there was an error.

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks, that's kind of what i was wondering about, just wanted to know if it's good practice to do it like that

Comment: I don't understand why moderator closed this, there are actual technical reasons to generate the ID on the client side vs server side, is not a matter of opinion.

Comment: So, there are legitimate reasons why you might want to create the ID on the client instead. Attention this is only valid for UUID, not sequential ids! The downside of waiting the server to reply with the ID, is that if for some reason you sent the request, but didn't get the response back (connection problems, server crashed, whatever), you are going to have to repeat the request and risking duplicating work on the server. If you create the ID on the client, this problem goes away, because you will repeat the request with the same ID avoiding dups. This is a niche use case, but it exists.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to store data in the server, you should never created the ID of an element in the client. You could add the same ID twice, or another user could use the same ID that you do, or use an invalid one, or -- you get the idea. You can almost surely avoid repeating IDS generating UUIDs client-side, but it is much easier, and more secure, to edit them in the server. Take into account that in the client you don't have any control in which the client sends to your backend. Despite what you do with JavaScript, a malicious user can always hack the request sent to the server and modify it the way they want, so you could end with IDs too long for you database fields, or with invalid values, or God know what else.

Comment: That part is kind of why i'm asking the question, the main thing that's confusing me is if i generate the id on the server side doesn't that mean that i will have to wait for the server to respond and doesn't that defeat the purpose of not refreshing the page?

Comment: No, you can use AJAX requests to update anything without reloading the page. If you want to allow the user to edit the list locally, and then submit all changes in a single requests, you could (if you really need it) to generate a temporary ID for items, but never use such ID to store them in the database. However, I don't see why you'd need a ID on this case, as you'll have references to the items themselves, you don't need to 'delete by id', as in this case, the items wouldn't be in the database yet.

Comment: This is not true for all cases, check my comment on OP.

Answer (score 1):

Generating ids client side is indeed bad practice for the reasons already explained. But the real point regarding your concern in my opinion is, even if you generate the ids client side, you still have to wait for that server response to make sure the resource is actually created. Server might be temporarily down, server-db connection might be down, disk might be faulty. You need that response in either case for a better user experience when there is an error. So I don't believe you're actually improving the overall user experience by generating ids client side.

Comment: This is not true for all cases, check my comment on OP.